# Bluez daemon is not running

Tags: networking, bluetooth, bluez, blueman

Sorry to ask this question again, I have browsed all the similar posts and tried a few of the suggestions without any luck.

When I try to connect to the Bluetooth manager I get this result.

[image]

Details below.

```
System:    Kernel: 5.4.0-122-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 9.4.0 Desktop: Xfce 4.16.0 
           tk: Gtk 3.24.20 wm: xfwm4 dm: LightDM Distro: Linux Mint 20.3 Una 
           base: Ubuntu 20.04 focal 
Machine:   Type: Laptop System: Acer product: Extensa 5620 v: 0100 serial: <filter> Chassis: 
           type: 10 serial: <filter> 
           Mobo: Acer model: Columbia v: Rev serial: <filter> BIOS: Phoenix v: 1.22 
           date: 10/22/2007 
Battery:   ID-1: BAT0 charge: 13.3 Wh condition: 13.3/44.4 Wh (30%) volts: 12.4/11.1 
           model: SONY Corp CONIS41 serial: <filter> status: Full 
           Device-1: hidpp_battery_0 model: Logitech Wireless Mouse M187 serial: <filter> 
           charge: 55% (should be ignored) status: Discharging 
CPU:       Topology: Dual Core model: Intel Pentium Dual T2330 bits: 64 type: MCP arch: Core Merom 
           rev: D L2 cache: 1024 KiB 
           flags: lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 ssse3 bogomips: 6384 
           Speed: 1596 MHz min/max: 800/1600 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 1596 2: 1596 
Graphics:  Device-1: Intel Mobile GM965/GL960 Integrated Graphics vendor: Acer Incorporated ALI 
           driver: i915 v: kernel bus ID: 00:02.0 chip ID: 8086:2a02 
           Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.13 driver: modesetting unloaded: fbdev,vesa 
           resolution: 1280x800~60Hz 
           OpenGL: renderer: Mesa DRI Intel 965GM (CL) v: 2.1 Mesa 21.2.6 direct render: Yes 
Audio:     Device-1: Intel 82801H HD Audio vendor: Acer Incorporated ALI Realtek ALC268 codec 
           driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel bus ID: 00:1b.0 chip ID: 8086:284b 
           Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.4.0-122-generic 
Network:   Device-1: Broadcom and subsidiaries NetLink BCM5787M Gigabit Ethernet PCI Express 
           vendor: Acer Incorporated ALI driver: tg3 v: 3.137 port: 1c20 bus ID: 02:00.0 
           chip ID: 14e4:1693 
           IF: enp2s0 state: down mac: <filter> 
           Device-2: Broadcom and subsidiaries BCM4311 802.11b/g WLAN vendor: AMBIT Microsystem 
           driver: b43-pci-bridge v: N/A port: 1c20 bus ID: 04:00.0 chip ID: 14e4:4311 
           IF-ID-1: wlan0 state: up mac: <filter> 
Drives:    Local Storage: total: 447.13 GiB used: 55.38 GiB (12.4%) 
           ID-1: /dev/sda vendor: Crucial model: CT480BX500SSD1 size: 447.13 GiB speed: 3.0 Gb/s 
           serial: <filter> 



Bluetooth details

Extensa-5620:~$ sudo /etc/init.d/bluetooth status
[sudo] password for andrewr:           
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead)
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)

Jul 16 08:31:02 andrewr-Extensa-5620 systemd[2]: Condition check resulted in…ed.
Jul 16 08:32:24 andrewr-Extensa-5620 systemd[2]: Condition check resulted in…ed.
Jul 16 08:33:31 andrewr-Extensa-5620 systemd[2]: Condition check resulted in…ed.
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
andrewr@andrewr-Extensa-5620:~$
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
sudo systemctl enable bluetooth.service
```

also make sure Bluetooth package is installed for your distro...
(FYI, search in arch linux forums)

Answer (score 0):

see this link for some options:
https://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?t=144923
In my case ( Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS), what worked was: `sudo systemctl restart bluetooth` ,  after which enable it

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).